# Is the recent version of Google Chrome still compromised by Vault 7?

Tags: exploit, chrome, macos

On [Wikipedia page about Vault 7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vault_7) we can read that Google Chrome (including other browsers) has been recently compromised (as of March 2017) by intelligence agencies.

Has the exploit already  been addressed and fixed in a recent version of Chrome?
I'm using Google Chrome 56.0.2924.87 (64-bit) on macOS.

Comment: Please read the Wikipedia again: Chrome was not recently compromised but only information about exploits were recently published. These exploits date back to 2013..2016. Since the full exploits are not known it is unknown if they still work. But given the many fixes Chrome adds with each release the chance is high that they no longer work.

Comment: Kenorb - please edit your post to fix the problems Steffen pointed out